# Existence of vectors whose image is Kronecker delta.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces

$E$ is a vector space and $\Phi_1, \dots, \Phi_n \in E'$ is linearly independent functionals where $E'$ is algebraic dual of $E$. Then

> There exist $x_1,\dots,x_n\in E$ such that $\Phi_j(x_k)=\delta_{jk}$ where $\delta_{jk}$ is Kronecker delta.

I know that Kronecker delta gives basis for dual space if the original space is finite dimensional but we have no information about $E$. Also I proved that $\bigcap_{j=1}^n\Phi_j^{-1}(\{0\}) \subset \Phi^{-1}(\{0\})$ if and only if $\Phi$ is a linear combination of $\Phi_1, \dots, \Phi_n$ which I think it can be useful. However I cannot see existence of $x_1,\dots,x_n\in E$ vectors.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you consider $\Phi = (\Phi_1,...,\Phi_n)$, can you show it is surjective and then quotient the domain to get a bijection?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Phi_i$ are linearly independent, using your observation:

$$\bigcap_{i\ne k}\ker\Phi_i\not\subseteq\ker\Phi_{k}$$
so there's an element $y_{k}$ such that $\Phi_i(y_{k})=0$ for all $i\ne k$ but $\Phi_{k}(y_{k})\ne 0$.

Then take $x_k:=\frac{y_k}{\Phi_k(y_k)}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. How can we assure that $\phi_{k+1}(x_k)=0$?

Comment: Very good question. Then just forget induction. I'll update my answer.